# How can I open Meta Stack Exchange in the mobile app?

Tags: support, mobile-app

I wanted to open this site in the mobile app today. I could not find it.

Manual look through all those sites is nigh impossible, searching for "exchange" or "stack" did not yield the expected result. I did switch the search to meta sites only.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Works fine on iPhones. Type "Meta ".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yeah... Turns out it's listed as a main site

Answer (score 2):

Blame my pre-assumption. For whatever reason in the Android app this site is listed as a main site.

Comment: ...That's because it *is* a main site.  Meta Stack Exchange has to kind of stand alone since it's the meta for the entire network.  There is no formal "Stack Exchange" site since that's a landing page for all of the network sites.

Comment: @Makoto while this sounds more like "it was easier to implement" than a logical reason, I can accept that reasoning.

Comment: Originally stackoverflow's meta was used. A while back there was a fairly complex process (there are blog posts I think, but can't look now) to split it off into its own site.

Comment: More precisely SO got its own meta and MSO became MSE